# Combination keys not working on windows 11

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-11, keyboard-layout, dll

I have a custom keyboard layout I made using MSKLC, it uses a few keys for combination characters (`͜`  and `͂` ). These work fine in a testing window, but do not work at all for me on the fully built and installed version. However, they work exactly as expected for one of my friends who also installed the keyboard.

**What I've Tried:**

- I opened the layout from the installed version (not the source version), using MSKLC, it showed the keys used for combination keys as having no binding
- I opended the two dlls the installer generated and discovered that they *did* have the combination keys where I was expecting them to be
- Windows onscreen keyboard also shows these keys as being unbound
- I disabled filter keys

I've tried everything I can think of but they simply wont work for me. I use windows 11, I would include the source files but since they work fine for my friend the issue clearly isn't easily reproducable. If anyone knows about this I would apprieciate some help.